# How to remove the onmouseout event after having assigned a function?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a problem, I'm assigning a function to the onmouseout event, but after running the event, I need to remove it. would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on your code, if you did this with d3, then you can say

inside your onmouseout event-function:

```
element.on("mouseout",func);

function func(){
    /*do your stuff*/
    element.on("mouseout",null);
}
```

If you bound the event via an event-attribute like `<div onmouseout="..." >` then you have to refactor this. In this case, simply use the d3 `on()` function to bind the event.

If you want to bind multiple handlers to the same event, you can use namespacing: By appending `.name` to the event, you can address them more specifically.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you added your event listener with [`d3`'s `on` event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on). their docs for removing an event is such:

> If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the
>   selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new
>   listener is added. To register multiple listeners for the same event
>   type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as
>   "click.foo" and "click.bar". To remove a listener, pass null as the
>   listener.

I can't correct your code, because you didn't add any.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use jQuery:

```
$(element).bind("mouseout", myFunction);
$(element).unbind("mouseout");
```

[jQuery unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) 
[jQuery bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

You can also use an optional namespace in the first parameter like:

```
"mouseout.myNamespace"
```

With this namespace you can bind/unbind multiple events of the same kind.

Another thing that maybe is interesting to you: 
[jQuery stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)