# Memory release of d3.js listener inside an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, memory-leaks, d3.js

As I already had some memory leak issue on some other projects, I documented myself on how to release d3.js event listeners memory.

I found that assigning a null value was releasing the memory [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534133/how-to-remove-the-onmouseout-event-after-having-assigned-a-function) [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814594/remove-event-listener-with-d3js-not-working):

```
svg.selectAll(".node").on('mouseover',null);
```

So before applying this solution to my code I did a first test to see how much memory was leaking.

I load the graph a first time and do a garbage collection.
Then several times: open a new simple view, come back to the graph and do a garbage collection.

[image: Memory leak test]

The Listeners and the Nodes already fallback to the initial value (754 and 1901). But I haven't applied the solution yet!

What is happening here, does D3 or AngularJS already do the cleanup for me ? Should I still apply the my solution on the $destroy event ?

The directive code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("appDirectives", []).directive("myGraph", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //values from controller
      var links = scope.data.links;
      var nodes = scope.data.nodes;

      //force graph size, affect the gravitational center and initial random position
      var width = 600,
          height = 600;

      //force graph initialisation
      var force = d3.layout.force()
          .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
          .links(links)
          .size([width, height])
          .linkDistance(60)
          .charge(-400)
          .gravity(0.4);

      //append svg element and width height
      var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
          .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");

      //add links
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            scope.data.info = d.source.name+" | "+d.target.name;
            scope.$apply();
          });

      //add nodes
      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "node "+d.type+" "+d.status; })
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            scope.data.info = d.type+" "+d.name+" <br/> "+d.status;
            scope.$apply();
          })
          .call(force.drag);

      //display node name on mouseover
      node.append("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

      // draw typeA as circle
      var gateway = svg.selectAll(".typeA");
      gateway.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 6);

      //draw typeB as square
      var switche = svg.selectAll(".typeB");
      switche.append("path").attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
          .type(function(d) { return 'square'; })
          .size(100));

      //draw typeC as triangle
      var ap = svg.selectAll(".typeC");
      ap.append("path").attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
          .type(function(d) { return 'triangle-up'; }));

      function tick() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
      }

      //use timeout to allow the rest of the page to load first
      setTimeout(function() {

        // pre render the graph
        force.start();
        for (var i = 100 ; i > 0; --i) force.tick();
        force.stop();

        //render the graph
        force
          .on("tick", tick)
          .start();

      }, 10);

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Nowadays, in modern browsers, the attached listeners should be removed automatically whenever the element is removed from the DOM and there is nothing reference to it. I think There might be something special in your other products that cause the memory leak.

Comment: @runTarm thanks for taking the time, that may be something like that